# Accessing polymorphic relations in rails through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, polymorphism

I have some model data which is collected via **ajax**. This model data has a **polymorphic relation** attached to it.

```
some_id: 1,
some_type: "foo"
```

So in the controller I can just do

```
Model.some.name
```

The problem comes when trying to access these attributes from **javascript**. The model data is rendered as **json** but obviously this **json** doesn't contain the relationship data.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load the related data that you want, either by translating the returned record(s) explicitly (as in a data transfer object) before serializing into JS, or else by using eager loading.

http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/